# Java Database Query not connecting

Tags: java, sql

For some reason, my application will not connect and I am unsure what is wrong, here are the errors I am getting which show something about a driver connection error. What I am trying to connect to is the `JDBC-ODBC Bridge driver` using the `Class.forName()` method.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3072)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at databasequery.DataBaseQuery.<init>(DataBaseQuery.java:32)
    at databasequery.DataBaseQuery.main(DataBaseQuery.java:24)
```

//code here

```
package databasequery;

//imports
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DataBaseQuery{

    //variables
    static String FirstName;
    static String LastName;
    static String ID;
    static String Symbol;


    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        DataBaseQuery q = new DataBaseQuery();
    }

    public DataBaseQuery()throws Exception{
       //driver manager
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       //stockTracker URL
       //connection
       Connection Connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:StockTracker");

       //Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
       Statement Statement = Connection.createStatement();

       //Query
       ResultSet Result = Statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users");

       System.out.println("Stock by username");

       //loop through the results
       while(Result.next()){
           ID = Result.getString("userID");
           FirstName = Result.getString("firstName");
           LastName = Result.getString("lastName");
           System.out.println("ID: " + ID);
           System.out.println("First Name: " + FirstName);
           System.out.println("Last Name: " + LastName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java **8**?

Comment: I remember that there were some incompatibilities for the JdbcOdbc drivers, you should try to look for them in Google

Comment: Is your ODBC connection defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html):

> ... JDBC-ODBC Bridge ... **will be removed in JDK 8**. In addition, Oracle
>   does not support the JDBC-ODBC Bridge. Oracle recommends that you use
>   JDBC drivers provided by the vendor of your database instead of the
>   JDBC-ODBC Bridge.